# Can TensorFlow.js save models directly to Firebase Cloud Storage (instead of saving to localstorage:// etc)?

Tags: firebase, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, tensorflow.js

I am collecting data in the browser and letting the user create a personal profile (their own trained model). I see I can save to localstorage:// which I can then read out of and write to Firebase Cloud Storage, but what I would really like to do is store to Firebase Cloud Storage directly.

The HTTP storage scheme seems to dictate the format of the POST (its multipart, as there are two files to be saved - a JSON file and a binary file). So that would require a Google Cloud function or similar to process it. I can do this, but trying to keep things as simple as possible (less to break then!).

Can I hook my own storage glue code into TensorFlow.js instead? Then I can provide the "save" and "load" implementation code, which I would proxy through to Firebase Cloud Storage calls.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "Firebase Cloud Storage" is actually the same thing as "Google Cloud Storage" (one of the oldest GCP products). Firebase just adds client SDKs that make it easy to access storage objects directly from web and mobile apps.

You can use any of the [Google provided SDKs for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to interact with it.  If you're writing nodejs code, use the [nodejs SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest).  If you're running entirely in a browser with a fully initialized Firebase SDK, use the [web client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

Comment: Thanks. The bit I was missing is you can create your own IOHandler implementation to hook up with the SDKs. I could not see a way to get a binary lump back from TensorFlow.js to store, so it seems like IOHandler is the way to go.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/1b88a535f7fa30166167463a16ebacb4cd40c797/tfjs-core/src/io/http.ts has a sample implementation.